# What has happened to the logo?

Tags: bug

Is anyone else able to see the logo of the site?

I can't. I only see a white bar...

Did something happen to it?

Comment: The logo looks fine to me. It may have been a temporary issue. Is it still not loading for you? If so, you may want to try a hard refresh (Ctrl+F5 in most browsers) and check that your firewall isn't blocking it.

Comment: @LoganM You've given me the idea to check an add-on (dark reader on chrome). It's odd that it only erases the logo of this community, and not of all the others I belong to... Thanks ;)